# Change relative to absolute via media query

Tags: css, flexbox, navbar

Is it possible to have a page that opens with 6 box items as nav menu, but when one is clicked to go to that area on the page, the nav becomes a standard fixed nav bar at the top of the page? Using only CSS (no JS).

- I am a VERY junior coder.

I have been unable to find this to be possible thus far.

Comment: Do you mean when the page is scrolled down, the nav bar becomes sticky?

Comment: Have you tried fixed or sticky - or is it some different outcome that you need?

Comment: I have a feeling it needs JS.. desired outcome: the page opens with the main 6 icons as links, once an icon is clicked, all the icons move up to the top as a nav bar

Comment: Fixed is the outcome needed, but the transition between the two states, I cannot work out how to acheive with CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use id and callback(#) that id as a link

```
<div class="navbar"> 
    <ul><a href="#page1"> page 1 </a></ul>
    <ul><a href="#page3"> page 3 </a> </ul> 
</div>
<h2 id="page1">this is page 1</h2>
<h2 id="page3">this is page 3</h2>
```

Comment: Yes sorry - the links are callback links within the same page atm.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime a link or a tab in the nav is clicked,a new webpage is reloaded. New webpage means a new html file and create a new css file to link with it according to the design u want there, yes doing position absolute and top 0; will solve the problem there to stick the navbar position at top.

I hope this helps, please feel free to ask me further !!